# In Loopback.js, how to run a standalone script without running the application?

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I'm running a standalone script to manipulate some persisted data in my Loopback application. I need to do this on production servers while the production app is running. I have it working like this:

Filepath is `./scripts/my-script.js` and looks like this:

```
'use strict';

const app = require('../server/server');
const Account = app.models.Account;

Account.find()
.then(accounts => {
  // do data stuff with accounts
})
.then(() => process.exit())
.catch(error => {
  console.error(error.stack);
  process.exit(1);
});
```

Then I run `node ./scripts/my-script.js`.

The problem is the entire application including the web server, boot scripts, etc, runs for the duration of the script, which means I'd have two instances of the app running. This happens because I get reference to the `Account` model like this:

```
const app = require('../server/server');
const Account = app.models.Account;
```

When I try:

```
const loopback = require('loopback');
const Account = loopback.getModel('Account');
```

It fails with:

> ./node_modules/loopback/lib/registry.js:304
>     throw new Error('Model not found: ' + modelName);
>     ^
>
> Error: Model not found: Account

How can I run this script (or perhaps use a different approach) to manipulate persisted data without running a second instance of the application?

Comment: How you fixed the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's your end goal here? You could use the loopback-connector-remote to hit the same app instance through the REST API.

You could also perform operations on the same db through the second app instance.

A third option would be to create a model of class `Model` (instead of `PersistedModel`), define its datasource as `null`, and instead of running a second nodejs process, you could execute the script by hitting the associated endpoint. I would just make sure you use a good security policy for that specific endpoint.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The goal is to manipulate data without downtime and without a second app instance via a script. Ideally I wouldn't have to add application code to do this.

Comment: If you already have your app running when you want to run the script, the only way you are going to have access to that app instance is through the REST API. As soon as you run your script with another Node process, your not going to have access to that same app instance.

If it were me, I would create and endpoint that would trigger a specified script when called, and just setup the security so only an "admin" role could hit that endpoint.

Comment: Ah, I see now. I could setup this endpoint to accept a `filename` parameter so I would only have to modify actual application once - to add the endpoint. Thereafter, I could simply add scripts push them to production, then call them on demand. Great solution, thanks.